# MS Graph SDK throws wrong error when retrieving photo that doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-api

When I do a test in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to get my photo which doesn't exist I receive an expected error...

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ImageNotFound",
        "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException' was thrown.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-11-06T02:23:38",
            "request-id": "4e44e92e-d5b5-4708-8128-01e39dcacc0c",
            "client-request-id": "1786d432-a855-9e1f-a68c-e4f1a7c345d0"
        }
    }
}
```

However when trying to perform the same request using the MS Graph SDK (4.8.0) in my ASP.Net Core web app a different exception is thrown...

> Code: AadGraphAuthFailed Message: Accessing service failed.

```
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(request =>
{
    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));

try
{
    var user = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); // THIS LINE WORKS
    var media = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Request().GetAsync(); // THIS FAILS WITH EXCEPTION AadGraphAuthFailed: Accessing service failed

    if (media != null)
    {
        model.PhotoType = media.AdditionalData["@odata.mediaContentType"].ToString();
        using var photo = await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync();
        model.Photo = ((MemoryStream)photo).ToArray();
    }

}
catch (ServiceException ex)
{
    var additionalData = ex.Error.AdditionalData;
    if (additionalData != null)
    {
        var details = additionalData["details"];
    }
}
```

I've tested this with both v1.0 and beta endpoints and both fail with same error. My API permissions are configured correctly and consented when logging in. Also the Me request works fine which suggests the Graph SDK has an issue when getting the photo but perhaps there is an issue with my code?

**Note that if a photo does exist then no error is thrown**

[image]

```
  "DownstreamApi": {
    /*
     'Scopes' contains space separated scopes of the Web API you want to call. This can be:
      - a scope for a V2 application (for instance api:b3682cc7-8b30-4bd2-aaba-080c6bf0fd31/access_as_user)
      - a scope corresponding to a V1 application (for instance <App ID URI>/.default, where  <App ID URI> is the
        App ID URI of a legacy v1 Web application
      Applications are registered in the https:portal.azure.com portal.
    */
    //"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "User.Read"
  }
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

This only seems to effect the Global Administrator (Microsoft Account?). When I create a new member user account within the same directory the code fails with correct ImageNotFound exception. Therefore is there a limitation with Microsoft Accounts?

Snippet of debug log at time of graph call...

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 925.0187ms 302 
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Net.WebSockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44308/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1843
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\MyPC\source\repos\MyApp\WebApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.21\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.21\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Code: AadGraphAuthFailed
Message: Accessing service failed.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-11-10T22:35:18
    request-id: a9becd68-8195-4ba9-9773-f33b21a61ce0
    client-request-id: a9becd68-8195-4ba9-9773-f33b21a61ce0
ClientRequestId: a9becd68-8195-4ba9-9773-f33b21a61ce0

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 18195.77ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44308/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful.
```

Comment: Could you provide the debug log of the error messages you get from Graph API with request id and timestamp. I have tested this with same version of the SDK and I get the expected error message. Also just pointing out that ` if (media != null)` will no run if the 404 error happens because execution will go to the catch block after ` await graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Request().GetAsync()` throws `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: ImageNotFound`.

Comment: @Danstan I have added debug log. Good point about the null check although for some reason I recall having to do that to avoid an error when accessing AdditionalData in some circumstances. Will have to check that again thanks

Comment: Your issue seems specific to your tenant or user. You will have to create a support request to get further help. Before that kindly update on whether this happens for one particular user or all users with the Global Admin role?

Comment: @Danstan Thanks for looking into it. To clarify further the account I'm using is my actual Azure Owner Account (the one I signed up to Azure with) not a normal user account with GA role. Perhaps this is the issue although I think my Azure Owner Account is still a normal Microsoft Account which was created when signing up to Azure? I will log a support request as you mention.